# What is the relationship between three metrics of RDS: Free Memory,Active Memory and Freeable Memory?

Tags: amazon-rds

What are the three metrics of AWS RDS: Free Memory (Enhanced monitoring), Active Memory (Enhanced monitoring), and Freeable Memory (CloudWatch monitor)?

What is the relationship between them?

Look at these two pictures.

The value of three metrics are different.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me answer your question in two parts.

1. What is difference between **Enhanced monitoring** and **Cloudwatch monitoring**?

As per [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html)

> Amazon RDS Enhanced Monitoring — Look at metrics in real time for the
>   operating system.
>
> Amazon CloudWatch Metrics – Amazon RDS automatically sends metrics to
>   CloudWatch every minute for each active database. You are not charged
>   additionally for Amazon RDS metrics in CloudWatch.

Meaning, enhanced monitoring allows your to monitor operating system counters while cloudwatch monitoring enables your to monitor performance counters **per database instance**.

2. What does Free/Active/Freeable memory represents?

[Enhanced monitoring info source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html#USER_Monitoring.OS.Viewing)

**Free Memory**

> The amount of unassigned memory, in kilobytes.

**Active Memory**

> The amount of assigned memory, in kilobytes.

**Freeable Memory**
[Official Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html#rds-metrics)

> The amount of available random access memory.
>
> Units: Bytes
>
> Freeable memory is not a indication of the actual free memory
>   available. It is the memory that is currently in use that can be freed
>   and used for other uses; it's is a combination of buffers and cache in
>   use on the **database instance**.

Comment: Is it to be concerned if free memory is low (200 mb) but freeable memory is large (3.5gb)? Performance is great and I am using an 8gb MySQL db.m4.large instance

Comment: I would say do not worry as long as performance of your db instance is great.

Comment: My reason for that is you still have 3.5gb agreeable memory which is used for caching by the database and can be reallocated if needed by the system itself.

Comment: With that said, I would still recommend to actively monitor your performance metrics.

Comment: So what performance metrics are important to know when to resize?

Comment: I'm not an expert the subject but I use amazon recommendations to decide when I want to scale up. According to which you might want to monitor ReadIOPS performance metrics and scale puro a point where your working set is in memory and ReadIOPS is low. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.Performance.RAM